# Passing a string parameter as a runtime Argument

Tags: batch-file

I want to open the particular path through the batch file. And I want to pass one node in path at run time. If I give input `Google`, I want to pass the string argument here. It will open the path

```
want to pass one node in path at run time . if i give input Google.i
want to pass the string argument here. it will open the path
C:\Program Files (x86)\google\Common
```

How can I achieve this?

My batch file:

```
@echo off
echo test variables 
set input = 
set /p input ="Choice"
echo C:\Program Files (x86)\%input%\Common
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\"%input%"\Common
pause
```

Comment: Your question title should be changed to say something different.  You were not trying to pass a runtime argument.  If that was the case then the answer I provided would be the correct one.  You just needed to fix the broken syntax you were using with your commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following issues in your code:

- there is a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> between the variable name and the `=` sign at the `set` commands, so it becomes a part of the variable name; hence the variable `input` remains empty/undefined;
- there are quotes within the path at the `cd` command, which are forbidden characters there;

Here is the corrected version:

```
@echo off
echo test variables 
set "input="
set /p "input=Choice"
echo "C:\Program Files (x86)\%input%\Common"
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\%input%\Common"
pause
```

I put quotes around the path at the `cd` command. Although not necessary for `cd`, many other commands cannot handle paths containing spaces if the `""` are missing.

---

To use the first command line argument instead of user input, remove the `set` commands and replace `%input%` by `%~1`. The `~` ensures that any surrounding quotes are removed. Type `call /?` in the command prompt for details on this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to run your batch file like this.

```
C:\>mybatch.bat Google
```

If so then your batch file just changes to this.

```
@echo off
echo test variables 
echo C:\Program Files (x86)\%1\Common
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\%1\Common
pause
```